# internet connection sharing Hyper-v virtual machine switch

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am running hyper-v. I created a virtual external switch and configured it to be shared with the host and the VMs. However the VMs obtain dhcp information just like the host does: same gateway, same dns servers etc but does not have intnernet for some reason. So I instead deleted the external switch and  created an internal switch and enabled internet connection sharing and shared the hosts internet connection with the internal switch. Now the VMs have internet. Internet Connection Sharing by default grants an IP address of 192.168.137.x to a computer. I have disable the firewall on the shared connection. How do I communicate with VMs that have an ip address of 192.168.137.x?? I can't seem to ping them from the host machine.

Comment: I was running the hyper-v hyper visor in vmware, not a support configuration, and the settings were not set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the hyper-v hyper visor in vmware, not a supported configuration, and the settings were not set correctly.